# Angular Server Side Rendering : Use Location Service to open an external page in new window

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I am using Angular SSR.
As window object is not available in SSR, I am making use of Location service as mentioned here https://angular.io/api/common/Location.

I am using the go() function to open a new page.
But its not working as I expected. Its appending the new url on top of my base domain as like below :

https://localhost:4200/https://newexternalurl.com/somepage

In addition, I want it to open in new window.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Hi, just so I understand what you wan't to achieve, are the steps: ` rendered page => click on object in page => open new window with same domain and sub paths` ?

Comment: No. I want rendered page => click on object in page => open new window with new external domain.

Answer (score 0):

The code in below article solved my problem.

Basically, we will use window.location.href but sneakily through a wrapper on browser window object.

https://willtaylor.blog/angular-universal-gotchas/